# AdMob interstitial error "Request Error: No ad to show"

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I'm developing an iOS application using Swift2 and Xcode7. I'm trying to implement AdMob but it doesn't display my interstitial ad.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    _interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
}

func createAndLoadInterstitial()->GADInterstitial {
    let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "interstitial_ID")
    let gadRequest:GADRequest = GADRequest()
    gadRequest.testDevices = ["test device id"]
    interstitial.delegate = self
    interstitial?.loadRequest(gadRequest)

    return interstitial!
}

func interstitialDidReceiveAd(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
    _interstitial?.presentFromRootViewController(self)
}

func interstitial(ad: GADInterstitial!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError!) {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}

func interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
    _interstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
}
```

I receive this error:

> Request Error: No ad to show.

[image]

Comment: *Request Error: No ads to show*, sounds like AdMob was unable to fill your ad request. Try again. Are you receiving any other errors/warnings? Which version of the AdMob SDK are you using?

Comment: @DanielStorm I installed AdMob with CocoaPods(pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '~> 7.0') . I tried again but received only that error.

Comment: However GADBannerView is normally displayed...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`Request Error: No ad to show.`

means that your request was successful but that Admob has no ad to show for your device at this time. The best way to ensure that you always have ads to show is to use mediation so that an unfulfilled request falls through to another ad network. Admob provides good mechanisms to do that.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have never thought that. I will implement the function soon!

Comment: what is meant by "mediation" and how is it implemented?

Comment: Mediation is where you configure your Ad client to presents ad from multiple Ad networks. Most Ad client like Admob make this easy by keeping the config on the client the same and allowing you to configure the list of ad networks via their web app.

Comment: Great idea may be you can combine AppLovin, InMobi, Tapjoy, Leadbolt with AdMob or different providers

Answer (score 3):

You should have two Ad Unit ID's. One for your `GADBannerView` and one for your `GADInterstitial`. Make sure your Ad Unit ID supplied by AdMob for your interstitial is **exactly** the same as what they've given you. Update to the [latest AdMob SDK](https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/download?hl=en), currently 7.5.0. Also consider calling `presentFromRootViewController(self)` at specific intervals or once the user completes a desired action. The way you have it setup now will keep presenting interstitials one after another because you are sending requests for new interstitials every time one is dismissed and then displaying the interstitial as soon as it receives an ad.

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADInterstitialDelegate {

    var myInterstitial : GADInterstitial?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myInterstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }

    func createAndLoadInterstitial()->GADInterstitial {
        let interstitial = GADInterstitial(adUnitID: "Your Ad Unit ID")
        interstitial.delegate = self
        interstitial?.loadRequest(GADRequest())
        return interstitial
    }

    @IBAction func someButton(sender: AnyObject) {
        myInterstitial?.presentFromRootViewController(self)
    }

    func interstitialDidReceiveAd(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
        print("interstitialDidReceiveAd")
    }

    func interstitial(ad: GADInterstitial!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError!) {
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    func interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad: GADInterstitial!) {
        print("interstitialDidDismissScreen")
        myInterstitial = createAndLoadInterstitial()
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. But I have already had two Ad Unit ID's for `GADBannerView` and `GADInterstitial`.

Comment: @MitsuhikoShimomura Check to make sure the Ad Unit ID for you interstitial is exactly the same as the one AdMob supplied you with. Using an Ad Unit ID that does not exist/mistyped will result in the `Request Error: No ads to show` error.

Comment: My AdMob console(http://i.stack.imgur.com/mMVQH.png). I copied Unit ID from there so I'm sure not wrong.

Comment: I noticed GAdMob doesn't provide ads for new members until a certain period of time, why I don't know? You can be sure from your code with replacing your ad id  with one of GADTestID's and I'm sure it will receive ad 100% because I test it more than 10 times and it worked.