# ios Admob native Express ad error No Ad to show

Tags: ios, admob

I am using ios to implement Admob Native Express ads.
I am using the test id provided by Google in the documentation : https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/native-express

The test id provided by Google is : **ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2562852117**

But when i use this id the error message returned is : **Request Error: No ad to show.**

My code is as shown below:

```
var nativeExpress_Ad_Id = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2562852117"

//initialize native express ad
    init(viewController : UIViewController , adView : GADNativeExpressAdView) {
        super.init()

        fromViewController = viewController;

        nativeExpressAdView = adView;
        nativeExpressAdView.adUnitID = nativeExpress_Ad_Id;
        nativeExpressAdView.rootViewController = fromViewController;
        nativeExpressAdView.delegate = self
        let request = GADRequest();
        request.testDevices = [ kGADSimulatorID ];
        nativeExpressAdView.load(request);
    }
```

I am not getting the point why it is not working?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AdMob interstitial error "Request Error: No ad to show"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32822987/admob-interstitial-error-request-error-no-ad-to-show)

Comment: @karthikeyan its not duplicate. I am asking about GADNativeExpress and that question is about GADInterstitial

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using constraints on the adView. If you use auto layout then there is a possibility that the width/height becomes less than the minimum values provided.

by adView i mean NativeExpressAdView

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that `height of adView` **>** 80  and  `width of adView` **>** 280 .

Cause , if you take accurate 280/80 , there is a chance to reduce size by 0.5 px.

Comment: I have checked the width and height and current width is 290 and height is 90 but still the same problem